# Список из файла, для запроса API

Tags: python, api

Подскажите как в запросе API передать список из файла csv.

```
import csv
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

#with open('test3.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
#    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
#    for row in reader:

to_send = [{'msisdn':"79000000000", 'shortcode':"text", 'text':'test2'},
           {'msisdn':"70000000000", 'shortcode':"text", 'text':'test2'}]

responses = {}
for item in to_send:
    req = requests.post(
         'https://target.tele2.ru/api/v2/send_message', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('123456789', '123456789'),
          data=dict(msisdn=item['msisdn'], shortcode=item['shortcode'], text=item['text']))
```

Несколько строк из csv

```
msisdn;Фамилия;Имя;Отчество

79000000000;сентябрь;777;890000000

79000000000;сентябрь;2 000;8000000000

79000000000;сентябрь;1 200;89000000000
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос структуру csv файла. Пары строк будет достаточно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишу пошагово. В принципе вы на правильном пути, используя `csv`-модуль. Достаточно просто открываете файл, читаете построчно, забираете нужную инфу. Поскольку у вас там может ошибка в заголовках `csv`, буду использовать примерный. Выглядит примерно так

Сам `csv`

```
msisdn;text;anyinfo
79000000000;sending to Rachel;blabla
79000000000;sending to Laura;blabla
79000000000;sending to Craig;blabla
79000000000;sending to Mary;blabla
79000000000;sending to Jamie;blabla
```

Как прочитать и добавить

```py
import csv

to_send = []

with open("access-code.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
    for i in reader:
        print(i, type(i)) # добавил для понимания, вывод ниже
        to_send.append({"msisdn":i[0], "text":i[1]})
```

Вы указываете разделитель как `;`, это значит что каждая строка будет разбита по данному разделителю. То есть если посмотреть, что содержит строка и какой тип можем  посмотреть на результат

```py
# OUT
'''
['msisdn', 'text', 'anyinfo'] <class 'list'>
['79000000000', 'sending to Rachel', 'blabla'] <class 'list'>
['79000000000', 'sending to Laura', 'blabla'] <class 'list'>
['79000000000', 'sending to Craig', 'blabla'] <class 'list'>
['79000000000', 'sending to Mary', 'blabla'] <class 'list'>
['79000000000', 'sending to Jamie', 'blabla'] <class 'list'>
'''
```

А сама переменная `to_send` содержит

```py
>>> print(to_send)
[{'msisdn': 'msisdn', 'text': 'text'}, {'msisdn': '79000000000', 'text': 'sending to Rachel'}, {'msisdn': '79000000000', 'text': 'sending to Laura'}, {'msisdn': 
'79000000000', 'text': 'sending to Craig'}, {'msisdn': '79000000000', 'text': 'sending to Mary'}, {'msisdn': '79000000000', 'text': 'sending to Jamie'}]
```

Первый член списка не актуален, можете его удалить

```py
>>> del to_send[0]
>>> print(to_send)
[{'msisdn': '79000000000', 'text': 'sending to Rachel'}, {'msisdn': '79000000000', 'text': 'sending to Laura'}, {'msisdn': '79000000000', 'text': 'sending to Craig'}, {'msisdn': '79000000000', 'text': 'sending to Mary'}, {'msisdn': '79000000000', 'text': 'sending to Jamie'}]
```

Адаптируйте под свои данные и все